# Spring boot - how to reduce log output from specific library?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, yaml

I am using the library `net.iakovlev.timeshape.TimeZoneEngine` and it is spewing a lot of [DEBUG] messages on startup which seems to be the default behaviour.

In `application.yml` I should be able to control logging level with but that's not working somehow.

```
logging:
  level:
     net.iakovlev.timeshape: ERROR
```

Isn't this the correct way to do so?

Comment: This is the usual way to set loglevels through Spring Boot yes. The logging levels set by Spring are not set right from the beginning of the startup of the application though so it might be that the debug logs are already spewed out before Spring even goes into its initialisation phase. If this is the case then setting the log level directly in a logback.xml file is the way to go, as per Alejandro's rather minimalistic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your log configuration file, and add something like this :

```
  ...
    <logger name="net.iakovlev.timeshape" level ="ERROR" additivity="false">
       <!-- YOUR APPENDER -->
       <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>
...
```